# How to loop through indexes and find matching values Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

So I have this function where I'm looking to find any index where the text is equal to the other objects text.

How could I do this using a for loop to figure out if any index (i.e: 1-10 or 10-1) matches the other in any random order?

```
const foundExistingProductWithExtra = state.products.findIndex(
        (product) =>
          product._id === action.payload._id &&
          product.extras[0]?.text === currentProductExtras[0]?.text &&
          product.extras[1]?.text === currentProductExtras[1]?.text &&
          product.extras[2]?.text === currentProductExtras[2]?.text &&
          product.extras[3]?.text === currentProductExtras[3]?.text
      );
```

This is obviously not the ideal way to do it but that's what I'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const currentProductExtraTexts = JSON.stringify(currentProductExtras.map(i=>i.text).sort();
const foundExistingProductWithExtra = state.products.findIndex(product =>
  product._id === action.payload._id &&
  JSON.stringify(product.extras.map(i=>i.text).sort()) === currentProductExtraTexts)
);
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. Unfortunately, it doesn't work quite how I was intending because it returns true when it finds the first matching extra item. If I were to add another index with a new extra object, then the extra shouldn't match unless it has that extra item and so on. It would look like this: [0] {text: "first extra"} [1] {text: "second extra"} [2] {text: "third extra"} and so on. If an item has all 3, then it matches but if it only matches one or two, then it isn't the same product.

Comment: @thatnewguy8 I updated the answer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @thatnewguy8 great, I've also taken one of the stringify operations out of the loop, since it will be the same value for each loop iteration